# How can I avoid unchecked cast warning in my generic recursive Iterator?

Tags: java, recursion, casting, iterator

It's somewhat odd that Java's collection framework has no iterator for recursive data structures.  Since I needed something like this, I wrote my own. First off, I need recursive elements:

```
public interface RecursiveElement<T>
{
    public Iterator<T> getChildrenIterator();
}
```

And then an `Iterator`:

```
public class RecursiveIterator<T> implements Iterator<T>
{
    private Deque<Iterator<T>> stack;
    private Iterator<T> currentStackItem;

    /**
     * Creates a new instance
     * 
     * @param root
     *            all children of this node are iterated. The root node itself
     *            is not returned
     * @throws NullPointerException
     *             if root is null
     */
    public RecursiveIterator(final RecursiveElement<T> root)
    {
        if (root == null)
            throw new NullPointerException(
                    "root argument to this iterator must not be null");
        stack = new LinkedList<Iterator<T>>();
        currentStackItem = root.getChildrenIterator();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasNext()
    {
        return currentStackItem != null;
    }

    @Override
    public T next()
    {
        final T result = currentStackItem.next();
        if (result instanceof RecursiveElement)
        {
            stack.addLast(currentStackItem);
             // Here is the warning:
            currentStackItem = ((RecursiveElement<T>)result).getChildrenIterator();
        }
        while (currentStackItem != null && !currentStackItem.hasNext())
            currentStackItem = stack.pollLast();
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public void remove()
    {
        currentStackItem.remove();
    }
}
```

That code works very well, but I do get a warning from the compiler in the `next()` method in the line I marked. It is clear to me why this warning occurs, but I have not come up with any solution on how to solve the problem without this warning (save suppressing the warning). Any ideas?

Comment: I don't think you can. Java's generics doesn't allow compound types such as `Iterator<T | RecursiveElement<T>>`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't think you can do anything about this. You have to cast here, and in the process you lose all information about the type parameter: The compiler can't know that if you have a `RecursiveElement`, it's always a `RecursiveElement<T>`, and "thanks" to type erasure it can't check the runtime type.

Comment: As @JvR points out, the problem isn't type erasure but the fact that each collection may contain both items and other collections. This necessitates a cast from `T` to `RecursiveElement<T>` which the compiler does not like (rightly so).

Answer (score 3):

The type checker is marking a real issue here.  To visualise this,  replace your `RecursiveElement<T>` with a generic `Iterable<T>`, which provides identical type guarantees.

When different layers mix different types, `RecursiveIterator` unfortunately breaks down.  Here is an example:

```
public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    final RecursiveIterator<IntElem> itr = new RecursiveIterator<IntElem>(new MixedRecursiveElem());
    while ( itr.hasNext() ) {
      IntElem elm = itr.next();
    }
  }
}

class IntElem implements RecursiveElement<Integer> {
  public Iterator<Integer> getChildrenIterator() {
    return Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3).iterator();
  }
}

class MixedRecursiveElem implements RecursiveElement<IntElem> {
  public Iterator<IntElem> getChildrenIterator() {
    return Arrays.asList(new IntElem(), new IntElem()).iterator();
  }
}

Output:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to IntElem
    at Main.main(Main.java:7)
```

Your options are:

- try to push the responsibility of recursing to your actual elements;
- try some wizardry to accept a finite amount of recursion by adding type variables;
- drop type safety and wrap in a filtering iterator.