# Iterator for a list of objects

Tags: java, reinventing-the-wheel, iterator

Given a list of objects, return an iterator for such a list. Looking for code-review, optimizations and best practices. Verifying complexity to be O(n) where n is sum of all objects, including elements of collections if contained. previously solved [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/32827/flatten-iterator-for-nested-list).

```
public class FlattenIterator implements Iterator<Object> {

    private final Stack<Iterator<?>> iteratorStack;
    private Object next;

    public FlattenIterator(Iterable<?> list) {
        if (list == null) {
            throw new NullPointerException();
        }

        iteratorStack = new Stack<Iterator<?>>();
        iteratorStack.push(list.iterator());
    }


    private void moveToNext() {
       while ((next == null) && !iteratorStack.empty()) {
            Iterator<?> itr = iteratorStack.peek();

            // if iterator is empty, then pop it from stack.
            if (!itr.hasNext()) {
                iteratorStack.pop();
            } else {
                final Object next = itr.next();
                if (next instanceof Iterable) {
                    iteratorStack.push(((Iterable<?>) next).iterator());
                    moveToNext();
                } else {
                    this.next = next;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Returns if there are any objects left to iterate over. This method 
     * can change the internal state of the object when it is called, but repeated
     * calls to it will not have any additional side effects.
     */
    public boolean hasNext() {
        moveToNext();
        return next != null;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the next element in our iteration, throwing a NoSuchElementException
     * if none is found. 
     */
    public Object next() {
        moveToNext();
        if (next == null) {
            throw new NoSuchElementException(); 
        }

        Object objectToReturn = next;
        next = null;
        return objectToReturn;
    }

    public void remove() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }
}

public class FlattenIteratorTest {

    @Test
    public void testIterator() {
        /**
         *  < <1, 2>, <"abc", "xyz">  <<1, 2>, <"abc", "xyz">> , a, 10 >
         */
        List<Object> genericList = new ArrayList<Object>();

        // integer list
        List<Integer> listInteger = new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(1, 2));

        // string list
        List<String> listString = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("abc", "xyz"));

        // nested lists.
        List<Object> nestedList = new ArrayList<Object>();
        nestedList.add(listInteger);
        nestedList.add(listString);

        genericList.add(listInteger);
        genericList.add(listString);
        genericList.add(nestedList);
        genericList.add('a');
        genericList.add(10);

        /**
         * A very simple test case.
         */
        FlattenIterator fi = new FlattenIterator(genericList); 
        final List<Object> listExpected = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(1, 2, "abc", "xyz", 1, 2, "abc", "xyz", 'a', 10));
        final List<Object> listActual = new ArrayList<>();
        while (fi.hasNext()) {
           listActual.add(fi.next());
        }    
        assertTrue(listExpected.equals(listActual));
    }

    @Test
    public void testEmpty() {
        List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.addAll(list);
        FlattenIterator fi = new FlattenIterator(list);
        assertFalse(fi.hasNext());
    }

}
```

Comment: I so want this to be named `Flatterator`!

Answer (score 5):

I'm going to hit the high notes on my phone and swing back later with details unless someone beats me to it.

### Allow `null`

Add a separate boolean field to track when `next` holds the actual next element rather than using `null` as a signal that it needs to be populated so that `null` elements can be supported.

### Avoid Recursion

In this case, there's no reason for `moveToNext` to call itself. Continuing the loop should have the same effect.

### Use Generics

Even though you're stuck using `Object` for variables which may hold an element or an iterable, you can still add a generic type `T` to the class and specify it as the return type from `next`. At least, I think you can. :)

### Testing

When using the `@Test` annotation, you don't have to prefix each test method name with `test`. However, you really need more descriptive method names, and each test should validate *one* specific condition.

Burn this into your brain: Arrange, Act, Assert. Arrange the test fixture in the initial state, perform the action being tested, and assert the results. It can become tedious to setup the fixture each time, but helper methods can ease the pain and promote DRYness.

Answer (score 4):

You have the general right idea, I think.

### Naming

`FlattenIterator` is slightly off, since it is a Verb+Noun.  I suggest `FlatteningIterator`, which is an Adjective+Noun.

### Generics

I agree with @DavidHarkness.  Even if the `Iterables` you pass in are non-homogeneous, your class should still be some kind of `Iterator<T>` rather than just an `Iterator`.

### `moveToNext()`

Of course, this is where the main challenge is.

The fact that `hasNext()` calls `moveToNext()` is weird, since `hasNext()` should have no visible side-effects.  Therefore, either it's wrong for `hasNext()` to call `moveToNext()`, or `moveToNext()` is lying and doesn't always advance.  In fact, the latter is true: `moveToNext()` is "disabled" unless `next` is `null`, which happens either when the `FlattenIterator` is freshly constructed or after you clear `next` at the end of `next()`.  So, just call `moveToNext()` at the end of the constructor and at the end of `next()`, but not in `hasNext()`.  Problem solved — no more lying.

As @DavidHarkness points out, encountering a `null` value among the iterables causes premature termination.  You don't want to test whether `next` is `null`.  Rather, I propose that you test whether the `iteratorStack` is empty to know when to terminate.

```
public class FlatteningIterator<T> implements Iterator<T> {

    private final Stack<Iterator<?>> iteratorStack;
    private T next;

    public FlatteningIterator(Iterable<?> list) {
        if (list == null) {
            throw new NullPointerException();
        }

        iteratorStack = new Stack<Iterator<?>>();
        iteratorStack.push(list.iterator());
        moveToNext();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")    // Needed for this.next = (T)next
    private void moveToNext() {
       this.next = null;              // Avoid lingering memory reference
       do {
            Iterator<?> itr = iteratorStack.peek();

            // if iterator is empty, then pop it from stack.
            if (!itr.hasNext()) {
                iteratorStack.pop();
            } else {
                final Object next = itr.next();
                if (next instanceof Iterable) {
                    iteratorStack.push(((Iterable<?>)next).iterator());
                } else {
                    this.next = (T)next;
                    break;
                }
            }
        } while (!this.iteratorStack.isEmpty());
    }

    /**
     * Returns if there are any objects left to iterate over.
     */
    public boolean hasNext() {
        return !this.iteratorStack.isEmpty();
    }

    /**
     * Returns the next element in our iteration, throwing a NoSuchElementException
     * if none is found. 
     */
    public T next() {
        if (this.iteratorStack.isEmpty()) {
            throw new NoSuchElementException();
        }
        try {
            return this.next;
        } finally {
            moveToNext();
        }
    }

    public void remove() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The null check in the constructor seems pointless to me:

> ```
> public FlattenIterator(Iterable<?> list) {
>     if (list == null) {
>         throw new NullPointerException();
>     }
>     iteratorStack = new Stack<Iterator<?>>();
>     iteratorStack.push(list.iterator());
> }
> ```

Without that check, the `list.iterator()` call will have the same effect anyway.

### Unit testing

Especially for a utility class that's kind of tricky, it's good to test more thoroughly with more unit tests. Here are some ideas. ([@200_success](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/9357/200-success)' proposed solution passes all the tests below.)

---

This is pretty much the same as yours, but slightly simpler and shorter:

```
@Test
public void testEmpty() {
    FlatIterator<Object> iter = new FlatIterator<>(Arrays.asList());
    assertFalse(iter.hasNext());
}
```

A simple, short and sweet sanity check:

```
@Test
public void testSingletonList() {
    FlatIterator<Integer> iter = new FlatIterator<>(Arrays.asList(3));
    assertTrue(iter.hasNext());
    iter.next();
    assertFalse(iter.hasNext());
}
```

Test that going beyond the end will throw the expected exception:

```
@Test(expected = NoSuchElementException.class)
public void testAccessBeyond() {
    new FlatIterator<>(Arrays.asList()).next();
}
```

The typical pattern of iteration is like this:

> ```
> while (iter.hasNext()) {
>     iter.next();
> }
> ```

That is, alternating `hasNext()` and `next()` calls. It's good to make sure that the implementation can work without `hasNext()` too:

```
@Test
public void testAdvanceWithoutHasNext() {
    Integer num = 3;
    List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(num);
    FlatIterator<Integer> iter = new FlatIterator<>(list);
    assertEquals(num, iter.next());
    assertFalse(iter.hasNext());
}
```

A simple test to confirm that null elements are handled correctly:

```
@Test
public void testNullElements() {
    Integer num = 3;
    List<Integer> listWithNull = Arrays.asList(num, null);
    FlatIterator<Integer> iter = new FlatIterator<>(listWithNull);
    assertEquals(num, iter.next());
    assertNull(iter.next());
    assertFalse(iter.hasNext());
}
```

Test the length of the iterator matches the length of the underlying iterable:

```
@Test
public void testIteratorCount() {
    List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(3, null, 4, 5);
    FlatIterator<Integer> iter = new FlatIterator<>(list);
    int count = 0;
    while (iter.hasNext()) {
        ++count;
        iter.next();
    }
    assertEquals(list.size(), count);
}
```

Sanity test with mixed types:

```
@Test
public void testMixedElements() {
    List<Object> mixed = new ArrayList<>();
    mixed.add(3);
    mixed.add("hello");
    mixed.add(null);
    FlatIterator<Object> iter = new FlatIterator<>(mixed);
    iter.next();
    iter.next();
    iter.next();
    assertFalse(iter.hasNext());
}
```

A more complex test with nested lists of several levels deep:

```
@Test
public void testDeeplyNestedList() {
    List<Object> nested = Arrays.asList(
            1, 2,
            Arrays.asList(3, 4),
            Arrays.asList(5, Arrays.asList(6, 7, 8, Arrays.asList(Arrays.asList(9), 10))),
            Arrays.asList(Arrays.asList(), Arrays.asList(), Arrays.asList(11)),
            Arrays.asList(Arrays.asList(), Arrays.asList(), Arrays.asList()),
            Arrays.asList(Arrays.asList(Arrays.asList())),
            12,
            Arrays.asList(),
            Arrays.asList(13, 14)
    );
    FlatIterator<Object> iter = new FlatIterator<>(nested);
    for (int i = 1; i <= 14; ++i) {
        assertTrue(iter.hasNext());
        assertEquals(i, iter.next());
    }
    assertFalse(iter.hasNext());
}
```